# xpath html query : select tnodes if these are not children of a given node

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xpathquery

I'm very a newbie with xpath started looking at it today :)

I have some html that have the following structure :

```
<body class="wrapper">
   <h3>someText_1</h3>
   <h4>someOtherText_1
      <a href="someLink_1"> link_1 </a>
   </h4>
   <p>description_1</p>
          ...     
   <h3>someText_n</h3>
   <h4>someOtherText_n
      <a href="someLink_n"> link_1 </a>
   </h4>
   <p>description_1</p>
</body>
```

Is it possible using xpath to select all the nodes after each h3? or more generally : given a node is it possible to select the followings n-nodes if these are not children of the given node?

I have tried with :

1. //body[class="wrapper]/h3/*
2. //body[class="wrapper]/h3/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `following-sibling::*`

All notes after hr:

```
//body[@class="wrapper"]/h3/following-sibling::*
```

The next one only

```
//body[@class="wrapper"]/h3/following-sibling::*[1]
```

The next three:

```
//body[@class="wrapper"]/h3/following-sibling::*)[position() <= 3 ]'
```

For more information have a look to [xpah axes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes)

Comment: It does exactly what I was trying to do, thanks (also for the link to the doc)